# Error while compiling with g++ MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, g++

There is some error. How sould I solve it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

error

Hello.cc:10:7: error: expected a class name after '~' to name a destructor ~

Comment: Your program is ok. Which compiler do you use ? What is the commadn you typed ?

Comment: Please show the full code. The compiler warning finds an error on position 7 in line 10 (Hello.cc:10:7), but the code you have posted only has 9 lines.

Comment: g++ hello.cc .. I know that it's only 9 lines so what the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Latest XCode will solve your problem